# How can I add a TextBox to an OxyPlot PlotView?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I'm trying to create an interactive plot using OxyPlot. I'd like to be able to show or hide a TextBox on the PlotView at will. Ideally, I'd like to be able to show the TextBox on the X-axis or Y-axis, but outside of it should also be fine.

I understand I'm able to add "annotations" to a plot, but the kinds of elements I can add is limited (e.g., text, lines, ellipses, images), but not controls. The nice thing about annotations is that they can be specified relative to the X- and Y-axis coordinates. I'd like to be able to add a TextBox using the plot's X- and Y-axis coordinates.

Comment: A textbox normally means an input control. I suppose you mean a label of some sort.

Comment: @PalleDue I do mean a TextBox because I’d like the user to enter some data as part of the interaction.